# Problem in a if inside the fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

The code inside my fragment shader is:

```
           "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
                "uniform float Opacity;\n"  + // range 0.0 to 1.0
                "void main() {\n" +
                "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n"+
                "    gl_FragColor.a *= Opacity;\n" +
                "}\n";
```

which works, I tried to add an if inside :

```
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform sampler2D sTexture;\n" +
                "uniform float Opacity;\n"  + // range 0.0 to 1.0
                "void main() {\n" +
                "    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n"+
                "    gl_FragColor.a *= Opacity;\n" +

                "    if(gl_FragColor.a < 250){;\n" +
                "         gl_FragColor.a = 250;\n" +
                "    }\n" +

                "}\n";
```

and it does not work, I cant figure this one out, I will appreciate some help

Comment: The color channels and the alpha channel are in range [0.0, 1.0]. So it has to be: `if(gl_FragColor.a < 250.0/255.0) { gl_FragColor.a = 250.0/255.0; }`

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! Please take your time to familiarize yourself with the site by taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), reading up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), going through [this brilliant question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and lastly, understanding how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Rabbid76 thanks! that worked

Comment: Also, floats in GLSL must have fraction part: `0` is an integer, `0.0` is a float.